# 'Access Denied' error when attempting to read binary contents of a file stored in an O365 group via REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to read the binary contents of a file in an O365 group and I can read the raw file in my web browser after authenticating with O365, but if I use the same URL in a REST GET request, I receive the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en-US">Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.</m:message></m:error>
```

URL being used:

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/yourSite/shared%20documents/test.xlsx')/$value
```

I confirmed my authentication with O365 is valid and not causing any issues. Is there another way to retrieve the same file using Microsoft Graph (`https://graph.microsoft.com/...file`) instead of `https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/...file`?

On a side note, it seems I can get to the point of the actual file metadata, but the '/content' doesn't show the raw file output I'm looking for [as indicated](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content) for OneDrive:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group-id>/drive/items/<item-id>/content
```

Comment: See the following URL link for an update to this question: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2815